# Returning a DynamicResource reference from the ViewModel

Tags: wpf, dynamicresource

My app has support for multiple languages and those languages are stored as resource dictionaries, so changing it just a matter of loading the correct resource, no restart needed.

In one window, I need to display some text based on the ViewModel state. Rather than having multiple `TextBlock` elements and switching visibility, I'm trying to return the `DynamicResource` directly from my ViewModel.

I tried creating a property returning a `DynamicResourceExtension` but it doesn't work, as the text returned is the name of the class, instead of the actual resource.

```
public DynamicResourceExtension TextResource
{
    get => return new DynamicResourceExtension("String.TextResource");
}
```

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TextResource, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I also tried returning a string and setting directly to the `DynamicResource`, but it also didn't work.

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource {Binding TextResourceKey, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}}"/>
```

Comment: don't try to reinvent the wheel. there are plenty of ways to implement localization in wpf app. research and pick one

Comment: To create a dynamic reference to resources, you must use the "FrameworkElement.SetResourceReference(DependencyProperty, Object)" method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.setresourcereference?view=windowsdesktop-6.0
Therefore, it is necessary to implement a wiretapping of the VM property and, when it changes, reassign the key using the above method.
I don't know any "out of the box" ways to do this. The easiest way, in my opinion, is to create your own custom Behavior for this action.

Comment: If your resource was a string array you could reference by index. Maybe you could expose viewmodel state abstracted via such an index.

Comment: Is the case where someone would need to change the language a common one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to return the name of resource from the view model and have the resource resolved using pure XAML markup.

The view model should either return an already resolved `string` value that you bind directly to, or you will have to write some code in the view that resolves the value of the returned resource name programmatically.

It's not possible to "bind" to the resource key of the `DynamicResource` markup extension in XAML.